# Find probability of this event

Tags: probability, statistics

Two teams play a best-of -seven series, in which the series ends as soon as one team wins four games. The first two games are to be played on A's field , the next three games on B's field, and the last two on A's field. The probability that A wins a game is 0.7 at home and 0.5 away.Assume that the games are independent .Find the probability that A wins in 5 games.

My answer to this question is 0.7*0.7*0.5*0.5*0.5+0.7*0.3*0.5*0.5*0.5=0.0875
But the correct answer is 0.175. How to get the right answer?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ wins in 5 games, then $A$ does not win in the first 4 games, so $A$ loses one of the first 4 games and wins the last game. There are two cases: Either $A$ loses at home or $A$ loses not at home. Each of these cases gives rise to two possibilities for which game $A$ lost, so your answer should be double what you calculated, which would indeed give $0.175$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.